# How to connect drive array to redundant motherboards?

Tags: storage, failover, sata, redundancy, network-storage

How should one connect a small storage array, four [3TB SATA drives](http://www.hitachigst.com/internal-drives/desktop/deskstar/deskstar-5k3000) for now, to two motherboards or controllers as a failover system? This means avoiding adding another single point of failure such as a single SAN device. A perfect world would have a [non-RAID] controller on an expansion card (PCIe, PCIX) made for exactly this task, or have the capability built into common motherboards.

I'm avoiding hardware RAID cards as this is just a backup solution, not a high performance server, and will be implementing ZFS (RAID-Z2, similar to RAID-6).

Comment: Seems odd you'd consider having redundant motherboards without redundant storage for a data replica of any sort - yet with what you propose, dispense with the idea of a SAN/NFS? Is money the rationale? You discuss a motherboard specifically, do you actually mean a full host (CPU, memory, etc) - sans drives?

Comment: The storage black has redundancy, @thinice. ZFS (RAID-Z2) has similar disk failure tolerance to RAID-6.

Comment: @thinice, I mean a motherboard with CPU and memory (and possibly controller card).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.  Sata is a one-to-one connection.  Even in San setups with multiple paths to multiple servers there is always a single point of failure which is dealt with by having multiple arrays.

There are multiple ways you can make that storage available to multiple servers eg. a NAS, but you are just moving the single point of failure around.

Comment: So that's why it's so hard to find these magical controllers.

Comment: SAS drives can have multiple ports, which *could* be connected to multiple backplanes (in practice I've never seen this, it's always a single backplane), multiple controllers, etc back to the server(s). You are correct however that SATA doesn't support any such mechanism.